# Android custom theme

Tags: android, xml, themes, android-theme

Hello I'm making a custom theme for my app. I want to have a custom ActionBar and background for the rest of the app (below the ActionBar). I'm wondering how to do the background. Right now I have:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/dActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="dActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#4C721D</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>    
</style>
```

Would I just have to do `<item name-"android:background"></item>` in `MyTheme` or would I have to create another `style`? After I create this do I need to put it in the res/styles folder? Also what are the API restrictions on this, if any?

Comment: Is that how I change the background? By adding `android:background` to "MyTheme"? And does this code go in the res/styles folder? Funny thing happened, when I first wrote this I was in that folder and now if I go back it looks completely different and doesn't contain this code

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to apply your theme to your application in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomActivityTheme" ... />
```

You can find all the information about styling the Actionbar [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Style).

To style your ActionBar with a nice Holo-look, try this [website](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I already added it to the manifest and my ActionBar is fine, I just want to know how to change the background for the rest of the app (below the actionbar). Sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: Ah, in that case you need to set the `windowBackground` attribute in your theme. Have a look at this blogpost from Romain Guy: http://android-developers.blogspot.be/2009/03/window-backgrounds-ui-speed.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below code in your Style.xml file

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Sample" parent="Theme.AppCompat">

   <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/primary_material_dark</item>
   <item name="actionBarTheme">@color/colorGray</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

Just need to use **android:colorBackground** as a name of item to define the background color like as below:

```
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/primary_material_dark</item>
```

Hope you get your answer,Thanks.

Comment: And when the theme's parent is a ThemeOverlay, such as for a toolbar theme, use `<item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>`

Comment: Note that older API versions ignore the `android:colorBackground` attribute.  Noticed this on API 16 - haven't tested others yet.  A possible workaround is to use `android:background` attribute instead.